# Javascript Browser Console.Log Append to Global Variable (google chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Im using Chrome javascript console commands to easily extract data from webpages. However, I would like to append each console.log command result that I make into a single variable then retrieve that variable when Im finish with multiple pages. Here is my ideal scenario to explain it easier.

**Scenario:**

1. Open console.
2. Visit page 1.
3. `console.log(1)` ~ store this into a variable **result**
4. Visit page 2.
5. `console.log(2)` ~ append this into variable **result**
6. repeat process..
7. get value of variable **result**.

I think this is possible but I do not know where to start looking.

Comment: If you are doing it manually by entering commands in the console anyway, why bother?

Comment: Are those pages on the same domain? Then you could use `sessionStorage` for this.

Comment: If you are extracting data from webpages, ie scraping, why not just use tools readily available on the web such as [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)?

Comment: @Bergi so then I would be doing 1 manual process only instead of copying the logs after each manual commands

Comment: @Bergi yes they are on the same domain. I will look into this. Thank you

Comment: @Bergi It seems that sessionStorage is exactly what im looking for. Can you add your comment as an answer?